# How to link to a collapsed hidden tabindex element with #

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, focus, tabindex

I am working on a glossary and have made a bulky file with terms in columns behind which are hidden texts (with `display:none`), in plain css/html.

Each entry looks like this in code: `<div class=w tabindex=0>`Achidrupa`<div class=tt>`Here follows hidden explanation.`</div></div>`

Instead of `:hover` I use `:focus` so the explanation is kept opened up in a sort of popup window, without use of Java or JS.
As there are entries with slightly different spelling I like to refer to the main entry, but not with the rather clumsy ‘‘See entry blah blah blah’’.

So, I like to make **internal links**, as we are used to with # and name or id in the linked-to element. But whatever I try, I cannot get another entry opened from the opened window with the link. Can I get some help with that? Very grateful for any solution.

**I believe I did not make this issue clear enough from the start. I have the following code, including tabindex=0 and with `.w:focus .tt{display: inline-block ; cursor:pointer; }` in css.**

`<div class=w tabindex=0 name="alpha">`1ste Entry Alpha `<div class=tt>`
    Follows text as explanation on alpha which becomes visible after a click on Entry Alpha, otherwise it stays hidden with css `display:none`. [Probably about or 100 words here.]`</div></div>`

`<div class=w tabindex=0  name="beta">` 2nd Entry on beta `<div class=tt>`
    Follows text as explanation on beta which `<a href=#alpha>`link to entry alpha `</a>` after a click. [Probably about or 100 words here.]`</div></div>`

What I need is the possibility to open window 1st Entry Alpha when I click in opened window *Entry on beta* and click on ‘link to entry alpha’.

I am sorry but the delivered javascript code and snippet didn’t work. It would not open any focused element. By the way, the glossary works great in this way, except for the internal linking.

Comment: The browser won't focus your link on page open, only scroll to it. You will need a little piece of javascript to do that.

Comment: Well, I already had in mind it would not be likely I would escape javascript. I will be very happy if you could help me out with a little script. Or someone else for that matter. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using javascript: get the hash, find element with corresponding name and focus it. The whole thing is wrapped in onload otherwise the browser wont focus the element.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
  if (hash) {
      var target = document.getElementsByName(hash)[0].focus()
  }
}
```

```css
.w {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.w > div {
  display: none;
}
.w:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.w:focus > div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a name="q1" href="#q1" class="w">
  Question ?
  <div>mopm adsma pomfdsapoi mfadsp fasdm pasofdm pasdofi mdfs apfd smapfdso amfp ad</div>
</div>
<a name="q2" href="#q2" class="w">
  Question ?
  <div>mopm adsma pomfdsapoi mfadsp fasdm pasofdm pasdofi mdfs apfd smapfdso amfp ad</div>
</div>
<a name="q3" href="#q3" class="w">
  Question ?
  <div>mopm adsma pomfdsapoi mfadsp fasdm pasofdm pasdofi mdfs apfd smapfdso amfp ad</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution may not be optimal though. It would be better to listen to click event and add a css class to the container. This way, the text won't hide when the user clicks anywhere in the page.

Comment: Thanks François-Xavier, but I could not work with it. I elaborated my question. Maybe it explains better my needs.

Comment: @ François-Xavier: can't we fiddle something with onclick()? So, when I click on a <a href=#link_to_alpha>asdf fdfs asdgga</a> Alpha will be focused? I have very little knowledge of Javascript, just sometimes scraped some little scripts from others, never written anything myself. The javascript you gave did not work unless I had to change div in the real description of the targeted div or that I had to change hash to # in the script, which I didn’t.